# build 2 login system (user & admin) using passportjs

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

I have built login system using passportjs and it works like charm. but now i'm struggling with how to differentiate login system for admin. since it use different database model schema in mongoosejs, i'm not sure how to do that. i have searched on stackoverflow and found this thread [Use multiple local strategies in PassportJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20052617/use-multiple-local-strategies-in-passportjs), however, i'm still can't fully understand how to apply it to my current passport configuration. in this code:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  if (isUser(user)) {
    // serialize user
  } else if (isSponsor(user)) {
    // serialize company
  }
});
```

what is isUser and isSponsor function do in details? i still can't get it and how to apply it into my code.

Here's my passport configuration right now. https://github.com/pepziman/gampangpoll-node-server/blob/master/config/passport.js

currently i still using the same local-login strategy for both my user and admin login, but its a complete failure since my user also can access admin page using their credentials. i have made a different login strategies called admin-login, using different mongoose model but can't understand how to change the serializeUser and deserializeUser function to meet my need. any solution will be appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: is admin some kind of users? is there a special reason you're separating the users and admins data? A typical way to do this is to assign 'admin' roles to a user and then with monggose you can use some instance methods to check if this guy is an admin or not.

Comment: @Shih-MinLee yes admin is a superuser, and the reason why i'm separating the user is because its db model is different, and the passport strategies is different too.

Comment: @AlbertLeonardoPisa did you find any solution for this, I am facing the same issue here.

Comment: @AlbertLeonardoPisa you are doing your DB wrong and making your life hard. A user is not an admin nor a student they are a user who may have a role making them an admin or student.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the below snippet of code, To have two different strategies(student and teacher here) , We make two local strategies and serialize and deserialize them accordingly. Hope this helps :)

```
app.get("/register", function(req, res){
    res.render("reg")
})

app.post("/register", function(req, res){
    var type = req.body.type
    if(type=="student"){
    var newUser = new Student({
        username: req.body.username,
        gender: req.body.gender,
        rollnumber: req.body.rollnumber,
        dob: req.body.dob,
        email: req.body.email,
        type: req.body.type,
        password: req.body.password
    })

    req.checkBody('username','UserName is Required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('rollnumber','Roll Number is Required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email','Email Required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email','Email Invalid').isEmail();
    req.checkBody('password','Password is Required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password1','Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);

    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if(errors){
        res.render('Sregister', {errors: errors});
    }else{
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err,  salt){
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash){
            if(!err){
                newUser.password = hash;
            }
            newUser.save(function(err){
                if(!err){
                    console.log("success in reg");
                    res.redirect("/student/login")
                }
            })
        })
    })
    }}
    else if(type=="teacher"){
        var newUser = new Teacher({
        username: req.body.username,
        gender: req.body.gender,
        rollnumber: req.body.rollnumber,
        dob: req.body.dob,
        email: req.body.email,
        type: req.body.type,
        password: req.body.password
    })

    req.checkBody('username','UserName is Required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('rollnumber','Roll Number is Required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email','Email Required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email','Email Invalid').isEmail();
    req.checkBody('password','Password is Required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password1','Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);

    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if(errors){
        res.render('Sregister', {errors: errors});
    }else{

             bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err,  salt){
                 bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash){
                    if(!err){
                         newUser.password = hash;
                  }
                        newUser.save(function(err){
                     if(!err){
                         console.log("success in reg");
                         res.redirect("/teacher/login")
                }
            })
        })
    })
    }}
})

//strategies

passport.use('student', new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done){
    var query = {username: username};
    Student.findOne(query, function(err, student){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(!student){
            return done(null, false);
        }
        bcrypt.compare(password,student.password, function(err, isMatch){
            if(err) throw err;
            if(isMatch)
                return done(null, student);
            else
                return done(null,false);
        })
    })
}))

passport.use('teacher', new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done){
    var query = {username: username};
    Teacher.findOne(query, function(err, teacher){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(!teacher){
            console.log("no teach")
            return done(null, false);
        }
        bcrypt.compare(password,teacher.password, function(err, isMatch){
            if(err) throw err;
            if(isMatch)
                return done(null, teacher);
            else
                return done(null,false);
        })
    })
}))

//serialize deserizlize

passport.serializeUser(function (entity, done) {
    done(null, { id: entity.id, type: entity.type });
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (obj, done) {
    switch (obj.type) {
        case 'student':
            Student.findById(obj.id)
                .then(user => {
                    if (user) {
                        done(null, user);
                    }
                    else {
                        done(new Error('user id not found:' + obj.id, null));
                    }
                });
            break;
        case 'teacher':
            Teacher.findById(obj.id)
                .then(device => {
                    if (device) {
                        done(null, device);
                    } else {
                        done(new Error('device id not found:' + obj.id, null));
                    }
                });
            break;
        default:
            done(new Error('no entity type:', obj.type), null);
            break;
    }
});
//login routes

app.get("/student/login", function(req, res){
    res.render("slogin")
})

app.get("/teacher/login", function(req, res){
    res.render("tlogin")
})

app.post('/student/login', 
  passport.authenticate('student', { successRedirect: '/student/home', failureRedirect: '/student/login' }));

app.post('/teacher/login', 
  passport.authenticate('teacher', { successRedirect: '/teacher/home', failureRedirect: '/teacher/login' }));


app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.render("home");  
})

app.get("/student/home", function(req, res){
  res.send("hi student")
})

app.get("/teacher/home", function(req, res){
  res.send("hi teacher")  
})
```

Comment: For both strategies it always writes data to req.user, how can we write data to req.teacher and req.student ?

Comment: There are ways to do what you want but they are not easy nor should you do them.