# Multiple local strategy not working in PassportStrategy

Tags: typescript, nestjs, nestjs-passport

I am working with NestJS framework. I have a `LocalStrategy` to authenticate users. Now I want another LocalStrategy named `MylocalStrategy`. For this I add two files: mylocal.strategy.ts and mylocal-auth.guard.ts

Here is my `mylocal-auth.guard.ts` content:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class MylocalAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('mylocal') {}
```

But when I use `@UseGuards(MylocalAuthGuard)` I get the error: *'Unknown authentication strategy "mylocal"'*.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Is your `MyLocalStrategy` registered as a provider in your module definition?

Comment: @ArnoldSchrijver yes it's registered in provider.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you manager to solve yours?

Answer (score 2):

You have to name your strategies and register in provider. For me, it works with following setup

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class LocalAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('UsernamePasswordStrategy') {}

@Injectable()
export class OTPAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('OTPStrategy') {}
```

UserName And Password Strategy

```
import { Strategy } from 'passport-local';

@Injectable()
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(
  Strategy,
  'UsernamePasswordStrategy',
) {
  constructor(
    @Inject(IAuthService)
    private readonly authService: IAuthService,
  ) {
    super({
      usernameField: 'user_name',
      passwordField: 'password',
    });
  }

  async validate(user_name: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
    const loginDto = new LoginDto();
    loginDto.userName = user_name;
    loginDto.password = password;
    const user: UserDto = await this.authService.validateUser(loginDto);
    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```

OTP strategy

```
import { Strategy } from 'passport-local';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Inject, Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { IAuthService } from '../services';
import { OtpLoginDto } from '../dto';
import { UserDto } from 'src/modules/user/dto';
import { plainToClass } from 'class-transformer';

@Injectable()
export class OTPStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'OTPStrategy') {
  constructor(
    @Inject(IAuthService)
    private readonly authService: IAuthService,
  ) {
    super({
      usernameField: 'phone',
      passwordField: 'otp',
    });
  }

  async validate(phone: string, otp: string): Promise<any> {
    const loginDto = plainToClass(OtpLoginDto, {
      phone: phone,
      otp: otp,
    });
    const user: UserDto = await this.authService.verifyOtp(loginDto);
    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```