# Local strategy error when using two different passports in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, middleware

If you have different user types which require authentication using two separate configuration files how would ya'll implement that because when I try to create two passports from a Passport object it doesn't know what the local strategy is even though it is defined in both config files and works when I only have one Passport. Thanks!

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/21898892/9175097

Comment: @MWO yes it did! now I just need to figure out how to deserialize a user to login as someone else haha.